# How do I import IE favorites to Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, bookmarks, import

I need to import IE favorites to Google Chrome. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3):

Tools Menu -> Options -> Personal Stuff -> Import Data

Answer (score 0):

Another choice would be to use the Xmarks Bookmarks Sync tool to continually synchronize your bookmarks/favorites between multiple browser types.  If you're like me you need to use multiple browsers from home and work.  If that's the case, then Xmarks has an extension available for FireFox, IE, Chrome and Safari.

For Chrome you will need to upgrade to the 4.0 beta version (http://www.google.com/intl/en/landing/chrome/beta/) and then [get the Xmarks extension from the Chrome extensions site](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ajpgkpeckebdhofmmjfgcjjiiejpodla). This utility offers a lot of control over how bookmarks are synchronized and unlike the Google Docs synchronization capabilities of Chrome, you can actually remove bookmarks when you create duplicates accidentally.